# Identifying if a node in a linked list is empty

Tags: c++, linked-list, exc-bad-access

I am having difficulty identifying if a node in a linked list is empty or not. I've been getting an **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x34)** error, but its not consistent. There are times where it's identifying that it the node is empty, but at times when testing it shows that it has an address. I had attach an image after attempting to debug and had put conditions to see if the node is empty

[image]

I've been trying multiple things to avoid this bad access, but don't know what to do. This might not be the best coding, but any help helps

```
struct InstructionNode *node = new InstructionNode;

if(temp_head == NULL){
    temp_head = node;
    temp_tail = node;
    temp = node;
    node = NULL;
}
else{
    temp_tail->next = node;
    temp_tail = node;
}

condition_flag = 1;

Token t  = lexer.GetToken();

if(t.token_type != IF)
    syntax_error();
else{
    node_tail->type = CJMP;
    condition();
    condition_flag = 0;
    body();
}

if(temp!= NULL){
    if(temp->next != NULL){
        node_tail->next = temp; //Bad access
        node_tail = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    else{
        free(temp_head);
    }
}
else{
    free(temp_head);
}

}
```

my class demo

```
class demo{
public:
demo(){
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

    node_head = NULL;
    node_tail = NULL;

    temp_head = NULL;
    temp_tail = NULL;

    temp = NULL;
}

void syntax_error();
variables *head, *tail;
struct InstructionNode *node_tail, *temp_head,*temp_tail, *temp;
```

How would I resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [example]. That means show the minimum amount of code that still reproduces the error, and that any one of us could copy, paste, and run on our own machines. That doesn't mean reduce your code to one line, and it doesn't mean copy-paste your entire project. It generally means starting from scratch, duplicating the class or algorithm that is causing you trouble, verifying that the problem still exists in this minimal form, and posting that here. It's hard to do, but it pays off in huge dividends.

Comment: What is `InstructionNode`?  And why are you using `free` in a C++ program?  This program looks like it was meant to be a `C` program, not a C++ program.  Also, what is meant by an "empty node"?

Comment: What do you mean by a node being "empty"? To me, that means the node lacks data, but then why all that code that looks similar to a linked list implementation? Maybe it would help if the requested [mre] included some output so you could clarify what you mean with a concrete example: "I expected ____, but I got ____."

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly (the line `node_tail->next = temp;` gives a bad access error), it's probably because you check if `temp` is not equal to `NULL`, but not that `node_tail` is not equal to `NULL` before trying to dereference it. If for some reason `node_tail` is `NULL` (like maybe the first time the code runs) this will crash.

To fix this, you will need to check and make sure `node_tail` isn't `NULL` before you dereference it, not just `temp`.